# How can I to add object to the List<Foo> via Realm Browser

Tags: realm

After adding a new object, the List is still giving me '0' in the realm browser.

Please refer here for screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should add the code in question to avoid your question being closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm one of the engineers responsible for Realm Browser right now. :)

At present, it's not possible to do that in the Realm Browser. I've filed [a feature request](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/issues/45) to add this as a new feature, and we'll look at implementing it soon.